# Woocommerce products only "in stock"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

There is the following code, the problem is that it displays all the goods in a row, regardless of status, but I would like to display only those that are "in stock".

```
function get_products($categories = array(), $product_type = 'featured_product', $paged = 1, $post_per_page = -1, $orderby = '', $order = '') {
global $woocommerce, $wp_query;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby'   => $orderby,
    'order' => $order
); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with your code, as your function and your args seem to be unrelated... but if you're just trying to get the products, try a custom loop:

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'featured',
        ),
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_stock_status',
            'value' => 'instock',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        // Do stuff.

    endwhile;

endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Note that I have not tested this and you clearly have something unique going on with how you're trying to display the posts, so you may need to make a few adjustments.